# Google Maps - Set height and width for the infoWindow

Tags: google-maps, infowindow

is it possible to set the height and the width for the google maps infoWindow?

I ask this because i have an ugly scrollbar on the right side

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Normal HTML/css methods should work.

Comment: can u give me an example pls: http://jsfiddle.net/L6PLp/ .
i dont know how to select the divs :/

Comment: @user2306309 please confirm are you using map api v2 or v3.

Comment: i'm not sure ... in the code from google is no version number. See http://jsfiddle.net/L6PLp/ ... But i think, i use the new v3

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L6PLp/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap the infowindow content in a div:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    content: '<div id="iw"><strong>Nachtclub Bar Rouge</strong><br />Französische Straße 15<br />10117 Berlin Mitte</div>'
});
infoWindow.open(map);
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/L6PLp/1/)